# How to implement Screen Space Reflection with DDA

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I am trying to implement screen space reflection with DDA.

http://casual-effects.blogspot.jp/2014/08/screen-space-ray-tracing.html

But, not working well.
Below is my shader codes.

This is vertex shader code.

```
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 color_0;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 mtxL2W;    // Local to World space.
uniform mat4 mtxW2C;    // World to Clip space.

out vec4 varColor;
out vec3 varNormal;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = mtxW2C * mtxL2W * position;

    varColor = color_0;
    varNormal = normalize(mtxL2W * vec4(normal, 0)).xyz;
}
```

This is fragment shader code.

```
in vec4 varColor;
in vec3 varNormal;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D s0;   // color
uniform sampler2D s1;   // linear depth.

uniform mat4 mtxW2V;    // World to View(Camera) space.
uniform mat4 mtxV2C;    // View(Camera) to Clip space.

uniform mat4 mtxC2V;    // Clip to View(Camera) space.
uniform mat4 mtxV2W;    // View(Camera) to World space.

uniform vec4 camPos;    // Camera position (World space).
uniform float nearPlaneZ;

uniform float maxDistance;
uniform float zThickness;
uniform int maxSteps;
uniform float stride;

float squaredLength(vec2 a, vec2 b)
{
    a -= b;
    return dot(a, a);
}

bool intersectsDepthBuffer(float z, float minZ, float maxZ)
{
    z += zThickness;
    return (maxZ >= z) && (minZ - zThickness <= z);
}

bool traceScreenSpaceRay(
    vec3 csOrig,
    vec3 csDir,
    out vec2 hitPixel,
    out vec3 hitPoint)
{
    // Clip to the near plane.
    float rayLength = (csOrig.z + csDir.z * maxDistance) < nearPlaneZ
        ? (nearPlaneZ - csOrig.z) / csDir.z
        : maxDistance;

    vec3 csEndPoint = csOrig + csDir * rayLength;

    // Project into homogeneous clip space.
    vec4 H0 = mtxV2C * vec4(csOrig, 1);
    vec4 H1 = mtxV2C * vec4(csEndPoint, 1);

    float k0 = 1.0 / H0.w;
    float k1 = 1.0 / H1.w;

    // The interpolated homogeneous version of the camera-space points.
    vec3 Q0 = csOrig * k0;
    vec3 Q1 = csEndPoint * k1;

    // Screen space point.
    vec2 P0 = H0.xy * k0;
    vec2 P1 = H1.xy * k1;

    // [-1, 1] -> [0, 1]
    P0 = P0 * 0.5 + 0.5;
    P1 = P1 * 0.5 + 0.5;

    ivec2 texsize = textureSize(s0, 0);

    P0 *= vec2(texsize.xy);
    P1 *= vec2(texsize.xy);

    P1.x = min(max(P1.x, 0), texsize.x);
    P1.y = min(max(P1.y, 0), texsize.y);

    // If the line is degenerate, make it cover at least one pixel to avoid handling zero-pixel extent as a special case later.
    P1 += squaredLength(P0, P1) < 0.0001
        ? vec2(0.01, 0.01)
        : vec2(0.0);
    vec2 delta = P1 - P0;

    // Permute so that the primary iteration is in x to collapse all quadrant-specific DDA cases later.
    bool permute = false;
    if (abs(delta.x) < abs(delta.y))
    {
        permute = true;

        delta = delta.yx;
        P0 = P0.yx;
        P1 = P1.yx;
    }

    float stepDir = sign(delta.x);
    float invdx = stepDir / delta.x;

    // Track the derivatives of Q and k.
    vec3 dQ = (Q1 - Q0) / invdx;
    float dk = (k1 - k0) / invdx;

    // y is slope.
    // slope = (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0)
    vec2 dP = vec2(stepDir, delta.y / invdx);    

    // Adjust end condition for iteration direction
    float end = P1.x * stepDir;

    int stepCount = 0;

    float prevZMaxEstimate = csOrig.z;

    float rayZMin = prevZMaxEstimate;
    float rayZMax = prevZMaxEstimate;

    float sceneZMax = rayZMax + 100.0f;

    dP *= stride;
    dQ *= stride;
    dk *= stride;

    vec4 PQk = vec4(P0, Q0.z, k0);
    vec4 dPQk = vec4(dP, dQ.z, dk);
    vec3 Q = Q0;

    for (;
        ((PQk.x * stepDir) <= end)
        && (stepCount < maxSteps)
        && !intersectsDepthBuffer(sceneZMax, rayZMin, rayZMax)
        && (sceneZMax != 0.0);
        ++stepCount)
    {
        rayZMin = prevZMaxEstimate;

        rayZMax = (PQk.z + dPQk.z * 0.5) / (PQk.w + dPQk.w * 0.5);

        prevZMaxEstimate = rayZMax;

        if (rayZMin > rayZMax) {
            float tmp = rayZMin;
            rayZMin = rayZMax;
            rayZMax = tmp;
        }

        hitPixel = permute ? PQk.yx : PQk.xy;

        //hitPixel.y = texsize.y - hitPixel.y;

        sceneZMax = texelFetch(s1, ivec2(hitPixel), 0).r;

        PQk += dPQk;
    }

    // Advance Q based on the number of steps
    Q.xy += dQ.xy * stepCount;

    hitPoint = Q * (1.0f / PQk.w);

    hitPoint = vec3(sceneZMax, rayZMin, rayZMax);

    return intersectsDepthBuffer(sceneZMax, rayZMin, rayZMax);
}

void main()
{
    vec3 normal = normalize(varNormal);
    float linearDepth = texelFetch(s1, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0).r;

    ivec2 texsize = textureSize(s0, 0);

    // Ray origin is camera origin.
    vec3 rayOrg = camPos.xyz;

    // Screen coordinate.
    vec4 pos = vec4(gl_FragCoord.xy / texsize, 0, 1);

    // [0, 1] -> [-1, 1]
    pos.xy = pos.xy * 2.0 - 1.0;

    // Screen-space -> Clip-space
    pos.xy *= linearDepth;

    // Clip-space -> View-space
    pos = mtxC2V * pos;
    pos.z = linearDepth;

    // View-space -> World-space.
    vec3 worldPos = (mtxV2W * vec4(pos.xyz, 1)).xyz;

    // Compute ray direction.
    // From ray origin to world position.
    vec3 rayDir = normalize(worldPos - rayOrg);

    // Compute reflection vector.
    vec3 refDir = reflect(rayDir, normal);

    // Reflection vector origin is world position.
    vec3 refOrg = worldPos;

    // Transform to view coordinate.
    refOrg = (mtxW2V * vec4(refOrg, 1)).xyz;
    refDir = (mtxW2V * vec4(refDir, 0)).xyz;

    vec2 hitPixel = vec2(0, 0);
    vec3 hitPoint = vec3(0, 0, 0);

    // Trace screen space ray.
    bool isIntersect = traceScreenSpaceRay(refOrg, refDir, hitPixel, hitPoint);

    vec2 uv = hitPixel / texsize.xy;

    if (uv.x > 1.0 || uv.x < 0.0f || uv.y > 1.0 || uv.y < 0.0) {
        isIntersect = false;
    }
    if (isIntersect) {
        outColor = varColor * texture(s0, uv);
    }
    else {
        outColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

I think `Q0.z` and `Q1.z` are always `1.0`.
So, I think `dQ.z` is also always `0.0`.

And, `dk` is always minus value.

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've tested McGuire's code in c++ and dQ.z is indeed 0.

Comment: I realise that it's been 2.5 years almost, but I thought I'd drop by with my $0.02:

1, In the original algorithm, `dQ`, `dk` and `dP.y` are obtained via multiplication, not division, by `invdx`.
2, On the other hand, I've hit a similar issue of perspective divide always landing me with a z = 1.0 when the z column of my `mtxV2C` was inverted (your scenario is slightly different though).